# Packaging a Qt/win32 application to post on microsoft store

Tags: qt, winapi, qt5, msix

I have a medium sized C/C++ Qt application that uses some win32 API functions. I compiled for release and created a directory that contains all the needed DLLs and resources files needed. I tested it on other machines and it works fine.

Now my question is.. how to package such application so that I can put it on microsoft store? Note that it is not a UWP app and it uses some functions from win32.

Comment: [Package a desktop or UWP app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps).

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696551/from-qt-ui-app-to-windows-10-store-app) work for you?

Comment: @IInspectable I mentioned in the question that it isn't a UWP app.. I don't have a Package.appxmanifest file and I don't know how to generate that. this is where the tutorial starts from.

Comment: The link says *"desktop **or** UWP app"*. Follow the instructions for desktop applications then if you aren't packaging a UWP app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Professional edition of Advanced Installer (it has [Visual Studio integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caphyon.AdvancedInstallerforVisualStudio2019)) and create an MSIX package ready for the Windows Store.

- Here is an article that takes you through the [MS Store publishing steps](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html)
- Also, an article that explains how to [build and MSIX package using Advanced Installer's VS extension](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-uwp-vs.html)

*Disclaimer. I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*